# ADF v2 Publish changes is listing all the artifacts as "new" instead of the 2 pipelines I modified

Tags: azure-data-factory, publish, continuous-deployment, cicd

I've searched for this issue on SO and couldn't find an answer.

1. I created a new feature branch
2. Modified 2 existing pipelines
3. Created a pull request - which contained the same 2 existing pipelines - and merged into main
4. From the `main` branch I hit the `publish` button in the ADF web gui and I get the following:

All the artifacts are showing as `New` when all I changed was 2 pipelines.
Those two pipelines are showing as `New` as well.

This hasn't happened before.

[image]

Initially I thought I'd done something strange.

So I checked out the commit that was the one previous to what I'd just merged into `main`.

`git checkout -b <branch_name> <hash>`

And did steps 1-4 above again.

The same issue.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish issues are absolutely the worst and most frustrating problems to try to solve in Synapse. I have seen this and similar before, so I have some thoughts but none of them are good. It sounds like a previous Publish may have failed midstream - I have seen this happen with no notice or error report.

- Have you checked LIVE mode to see if it is registering anything? Can you verify/validate its currency?
- Is there any chance someone changed the Git configuration? Or worse updated the repo outside Synapse?

**THINGS TO TRY:**

- Sign out of Synapse, close the browser, reboot your machine. Try again. This could resolve any cache issues.
- If that doesn't help, wait a few hours or even overnight. Try again. This could resolve an Azure service issue.
- Revert the Commit in Git, reload main in Synapse. Try again. This could resolve any Git integration issues.

**USE AT YOUR OWN RISK:**

These options are present but I find them suspect and would proceed with great caution.

- Inside Synapse, under Management > Git Integration, there is an option for "Overwrite Live Mode".
- You can disconnect and reconnect your Git repository. and see if that helps.

**LAST RESORT**

- If none of this helps, put in a support ticket and hope for the best.